# SQL query: NULL values that should not be NULL when using aggregate function with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, aggregate-functions

i dont have much expiriance with SQL and i am trying to crack my head on this query.
i have 3 tables: Projects, Calculator and partialBilling
(note: the 'calculator' columns you see at the code ive added 'k','l','m' etc are real...i didnt gave them those names...).

the query is working fine but **part** of the values that i am expecting from the aggregate function ('sumofTotal' column) are  returning as null values and and they should not be null.
I would be grateful if someone point out the mistake in the query.

```
SELECT Projects.SpCall,Projects.CustName,Projects.CustNumber
,Projects.ReceiveDate,Projects.StartDate,Projects.ProjectType
,Calculator.AN,Projects.Professional,Projects.PmUserName
,Projects.AcountManager,Projects.CrmCallNum,Projects.ProjectCategory
,Projects.CallNum,Projects.ContactName,Projects.ContactPhone
,Projects.ContactEmail,Projects.HiddenNote,Projects.RowColor
, Projects.HeaderCellText,
 SUM(Calculator.K + Calculator.L + Calculator.M + Calculator.N + Calculator.AD + Calculator.AR) AS sumofTotal
 ,partialBilling.Ammount FROM Projects LEFT JOIN Calculator ON Projects.SpCall=Calculator.AQ
  LEFT JOIN partialBilling ON Projects.SpCall = partialBilling.spCall
   WHERE PmUserName= 'JOHN DOE'AND OpertionalStatus
    <> 'Billed' AND OpertionalStatus<> 'Finished' AND
     OpertionalStatus<> 'Passed To Billing' AND OpertionalStatus<> 'Scanning' 
     AND OpertionalStatus<> 'Ended' 
     AND OpertionalStatus<> 'Green Billing' 
     AND (GeneralStatus= 'Passed To Project Manager' 
     OR GeneralStatus= 'Astrategic Project') 
     GROUP BY Projects.SpCall,Projects.CustName,Projects.CustNumber
     ,Projects.ReceiveDate,Projects.StartDate,Projects.ProjectType
     ,Calculator.AN,Projects.Professional,Projects.PmUserName
     ,Projects.AcountManager,Projects.CrmCallNum,Projects.ProjectCategory
     ,Projects.CallNum,Projects.ContactName,Projects.ContactPhone
     ,Projects.ContactEmail,Projects.HiddenNote,Projects.RowColor
     , Projects.HeaderCellText,partialBilling.Ammount;
```

Comment: Simplify the problem and it will be easier for everybody (incl you) to understand it. Much less columns, some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: tnx, working on it. few minuets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of proprietary `IFNULL` better use Standard SQL `COALESCE`:

```
SUM(COALESCE(Calculator.K,0) + COALESCE(Calculator.L,0), ...`
```

Or maybe a bit more efficient:

```
SUM(COALESCE(Calculator.K,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(Calculator.L,0)), ...`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use IFNULL()

```
SUM(IFNULL(Calculator.K,0) + ... + IFNULL(Calculator.AR,0)) AS sumofTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like `ifnull('column_name' , '')` in place of `column_name`.